# How to modify outbound UDP traffic with a Winsock LSP?

Tags: c++, windows, udp, winsock, ipv6

I'm building an application that needs to modify DHCPv6 packets dynamically before they hit the wire. I'm doing some heavily proprietary work with DHCPv6 vendor options, and I need the ability to examine and modify those options in-memory before they are transmitted.

I've built a proof-of-concept layered service provider on top of Winsock by modifying the Microsoft sample code. It intercepts outgoing HTTP packets, changes the referrer-agent to something funny, and sends the packet on its way. Verified in Wireshark, works great.

It was also straightforward to change my installer code so that my LSP gets chained in on top of UDP/IPv6 rather than TCP/IPv4, and now, with a debugger attached, I can see myself getting callbacks with stacks leading into the DHCP server. However, I can no longer see the buffers in memory.

`WSPSend` and `WSPConnect` don't get called, since we're on a connectionless protocol--that makes sense. I do get a consistent callback in `WSPSendTo` but the `lpBuffers` member, which in my HTTP prototype contained the buffer representing the outgoing packet, is `NULL`.

Am I going about this completely the wrong way, or is there another Winsock operation I need to override? I'd be happy to go in another direction if an LSP is the wrong way to go, but outside libraries are a very tough sell for this application--otherwise, I'd be looking at Winpcap.

EDIT: Wow, this was a long time ago. For those coming behind me, this ultimately worked fine. I'm embarrassed to say that the issue was that I was compiling with optimizations that prevented me from seeing the correct data in the debugger. When I stopped being lazy and dumped the bytes to a file, I saw that all was well.

Comment: Are you sure you declared `WSPSendTo()` correctly?  Are the other parameter values correct?

Answer (score 0):

LSP does can only intercept Winsock traffic, DHCP is at a lower layer, you need a different technology to do this, for example: NDIS, TDI (Will not work on Win8) or WFP (Will not work on XP)

Comment: Thanks Barak; I was concerned about that, so before I began this whole exercise, I looked to make sure that the svchost.exe which contains ONLY the DHCP server does in fact load w2_32.dll (it does).

But, to sum up, you're saying that an LSP can't possibly work here in spite of the fact that I'm seeing that DLL get loaded, and in spite of the fact that I am getting a callback, just with strange buffers?